# Extracting final p-value statistic from an lm lapply loop with multiple models

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, sapply

I have the following code that automatically performs lm between my independent variable (Kpl) and all my other dependent variables (Y1, Y2, ...., Yi):

`linear_summary <- lapply(testdata[,-1], function(x) summary(lm(Kpl ~ x)))`

The output for this is

```
Call:
lm(formula = Kpl ~ x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.37567 -0.52392  0.04236  0.67444  0.81316 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.7282     0.3456   5.001 0.000402 ***
x            -0.1550     0.2712  -0.571 0.579196    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.772 on 11 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02883,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.05946 
F-statistic: 0.3265 on 1 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.5792


$Y2

Call:
lm(formula = Kpl ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.2472 -0.4236 -0.2057  0.7140  1.0348 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.6900     0.9010   0.766    0.460
x             0.8832     0.8767   1.007    0.335

Residual standard error: 0.7495 on 11 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.08447,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.001238 
F-statistic: 1.015 on 1 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.3354
```

Etc. (I have truncated it for just the first 2 correlations)

I wanted to extract the final p-value for the whole model for each of the instances (0.5792 and 0.3354 in these two cases). Ideally this would come in some sort of table form with the associated correlation variable, i.e. Y1=0.5792 Y2=0.3354.

Most of the info I can find either seem to only work for a single correlation (as opposed to an sapply with multiple correlations) or I do not seem to get it to work, which could be a problem with my original code.

Any suggestions for a person just starting with R on how to solve this?

Edit: The data looks something like this

```
|    X     |     Y1      |     Y2      |     Y3      |     Y4      |
| -------- | ------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
| 0.33767  | 2.33063062  | 1.013212308 | 1.277996888 | 1.373238355 |
| 0.33767  | 0.095967324 | 0.508830529 | 0.789257027 | 0.815877121 |
| 1.010474 | 2.344657045 | 0.842490752 | 1.240582283 | 1.262360905 |
| 1.010474 | 0.08135992  | 0.912535398 | 0.384427466 | 0.409817599 |
| 1.183276 | 0.135626937 | 0.967877981 | 0.505801442 | 0.576288093 |
| 1.536974 | 1.507146148 | 1.428839993 | 1.316569449 | 1.392022619 |
| 1.536974 | 1.255210981 | 1.191822955 | 1.395769591 | 1.41903939  |
| 2.017965 | 1.410299711 | 1.121560244 | 1.369835675 | 1.385143026 |
| 2.017965 | 1.032587109 | 1.372235121 | 1.390878783 | 1.42741762  |
| 2.3436   | 1.275999998 | 0.930400789 | 1.19877482  | 1.217540034 |
| 2.3436   | 1.250513383 | 1.063880146 | 1.206719195 | 1.23325973  |
| 2.387598 | 0.182866909 | 0.89588293  | 0.416923749 | 0.45364797  |
| 2.387598 | 0.097133916 | 0.750430855 | 0.506463633 | 0.03434754  |
```

These are the actual values that I used to get the correlations above

Answer (score 2):

I think the p-value is not stored, you need to calculate it from the fstatistics, maybe something like this:

```
set.seed(111)
testdata = data.frame(Kpl = rnorm(100), Y1 = rnorm(100),
                      Y2 = rnorm(100), Y3 = rnorm(100))

IV = colnames(testdata)[-1]
DV = "Kpl"

linear_summary <- lapply(IV,function(x){
         summary(lm(reformulate(response=DV,termlabels=x),data=testdata))
                         })

names(linear_summary) = IV

tab = lapply(IV,function(x){
  p = with(
       linear_summary[[x]],
       pf(fstatistic[1],fstatistic[2],fstatistic[3],lower.tail=FALSE)
          )
  data.frame(IV = x, p = p)
})

do.call(rbind,tab)

       IV         p
value  Y1 0.5757187
value1 Y2 0.4922582
value2 Y3 0.4009439
```

Check for example first summary:

```
linear_summary[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = reformulate(response = DV, termlabels = x), data = testdata)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.94515 -0.73325  0.05448  0.57901  2.76026 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.01382    0.10747  -0.129    0.898
Y1          -0.05950    0.10597  -0.562    0.576

Residual standard error: 1.075 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.003207,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.006964 
F-statistic: 0.3153 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.5757
```

Comment: `bb <- Filter(function(x) {
  summary(x)$adj.r.squared > .83}, models)` is it possible to add p value filter to this along  with adj.r.squared  ? i tried but i think i'm doing the syntax wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ok I edited my code in the following way:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)

df %>%    # Solution 1
  pivot_longer(-X) %>%
  group_split(name) %>%
  set_names(nm = map(., ~ first(.x$name))) %>%
  map(~ tidy(lm(X ~ value, data = .))) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "var") %>%
  filter(term == "value")

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  var   term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Y1    value  -0.155      0.271   -0.571    0.579
2 Y2    value   0.883      0.877    1.01     0.335
3 Y3    value   0.0341     0.552    0.0618   0.952
4 Y4    value  -0.158      0.469   -0.337    0.743
```

Or you can use this:

```
df %>%    # Solution 2
  pivot_longer(Y1:Y4) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(.by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(models = map(data, ~ lm(X ~ value, data = .)),
         glance = map(models, glance)) %>%
  unnest(glance)

# A tibble: 4 x 15
# Groups:   name [4]
  name  data    models r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC
  <chr> <list>  <list>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Y1    <tibbl~ <lm>    0.0288        -0.0595  0.772   0.327     0.579     1  -14.0  34.0  35.7
2 Y2    <tibbl~ <lm>    0.0845         0.00124 0.750   1.01      0.335     1  -13.6  33.2  34.9
3 Y3    <tibbl~ <lm>    0.000348      -0.0905  0.783   0.00382   0.952     1  -14.2  34.4  36.1
4 Y4    <tibbl~ <lm>    0.0102        -0.0798  0.779   0.113     0.743     1  -14.1  34.2  35.9
# ... with 3 more variables: deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

I know you already got your answer but here I presented 2 other solutions. Thought it may be ok to learn alternative ways of dealing with a problem and thank you for your question, it was very good.

Comment: Added example data to the question, sorry if you got 100 notices for edits, I keep using enter accidentally!   

I am still at the very beginning of my R journey so if you could help me with the code it would be greatly appreciated, otherwise I will try and figure it out from what you wrote.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Would you please explain what are these? you have written all the data rowwise?

Comment: Yes, the data is all there. X is my Kpl value (independent variable) and the Y1, ..., Yi are my dependent variables. I do not know if I made the table wrong though. What I want to do is correlate X with all of the Yi variables

Comment: running the code as  
       map("testdata", ~ lm(kpl ~ Y1, data = testdata)) %>%
  map(summary) %>%
  map_dbl("p.value")   
gives the following error     Error: Result 1 must be a single double, not NULL of length 0

Comment: I could not get this to work at the moment, but I will try later. Thanks for the tip

Comment: i have the same question if we want to get pvalue for rowwise is it possible?